# Question found in the VtC queue, but it doesn't have active close votes, how is it possible?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I found [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26419/1054) question is the VtC review queue. If you can see that, the review entity is [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/close/14806).

The question has no active close votes.

I check the review queues of the related site multiple times in a day, so a vote timeout is highly unlikely.

How could a question go into the VtC queue if it doesn't have a close vote?

Comment: A VtC flag maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what flagging does.

Users with insufficient reputation to cast close votes can flag something that should be closed and that has the effect of putting the question in the close queue but since those users can not vote to close, there will be no existing close votes.